# Filter using field from child entity

Tags: java, eclipselink

I have class `Person` containing field `age`, Class `Student` extends `Person` containing field `class`, and class `Teacher` extends `Person` and containing field `salary`.

I want to get all Person who are in class X, if they are Student, and earn 1500$, if they are Teacher, using the same jpql query. The query must return a list of Person. I can make two query and make a method that call both query and join the result but is there a better solution.

I hope I was able to explain

Comment: Have you tried `select p from Person p where p.salary = 1500 or p.clazz = 'X'`? AFAIK, with Hibernate at least, this would work fine.

Comment: no, i haven't but is it possible to work in this simple way. i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "TYPE" and JPA 2.1 "TREAT" to filter on the class.

```
"SELECT p from Person p where treat(p as Teacher).salary = 1500 or TYPE(p) = Student"
```

If you cannot use JPA 2.1, you can use a subquery on Teacher to return Teacher ids with salary=1500, and use the result in the main query.

```
"SELECT p from Person p where p.id in(SELECT t.id from Teacher t where t.salary=1500) or TYPE(p) = Student"
```

Comment: I think you mean JPA 2.1. I've seen no mention of TREAT in the JPA 2.0 spec. +1 though.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I am using glassfish 3.1.2 which support jpa 2.0 so i have to change application server right ?

Comment: No, you can replace the EclipseLink version within Glassfish to EL 2.5 or later.  There are a few posts on how to since Glassfish uses the OSGI bundles, but here's one I found quickly: http://computingat40s.wordpress.com/installing-glassfish-3-1-2-2/